# A templated function to always retrieve the value of T, being T an universal reference

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference

I want to have a helper function that helps me to get the value or the value of the pointee when its a pointer.

For example, I want to substract a pair numerical values or the values for the types that defines an overload for the - operator.

This is my code:

```
template <typename T>
T value_retriever(const T&& val) {
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<decltype(val)> || std::is_reference_v<decltype(val)>)
        return *val;
    else
        return std::forward<T>(val);
}


template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto minus(const T&& lhs, const T&& rhs) -> T {
    return value_retriever(std::move(lhs)) - value_retriever(std::move(rhs));
}
```

And this are the errors that I am facing:

```
In module 'math' imported from zero\main.cpp:8:
In module 'math.ops' imported from zero/ifc/math/math.cppm:3:
zero/ifc/math/ops/arithmetic.cppm:25:16: error: cannot initialize return
      object of type 'const int *' with an rvalue of type 'long long'
        return value_retriever(std::forward<T>(lhs)) - value_retriever(std::forward<T>(rhs));
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
zero\main.cpp:38:83: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'zero::math::minus<const int *>' requested here
    std::cout << "Subtraction of two integer l-value references: " << zero::math::minus(&a, &b) << "\n\n";
                                                                                  ^
In module 'math' imported from zero\main.cpp:8:
In module 'math.ops' imported from zero/ifc/math/math.cppm:3:
zero/ifc/math/ops/arithmetic.cppm:9:20: error: indirection requires pointer
      operand ('int' invalid)
            return *val;
                   ^~~~
zero/ifc/math/ops/arithmetic.cppm:25:16: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization 'zero::math::value_retriever<int>' requested here
        return value_retriever(std::forward<T>(lhs)) - value_retriever(std::forward<T>(rhs));
               ^
zero/ifc/math/ops/arithmetic.cppm:9:20: error: cannot initialize return
      object of type 'const int *' with an lvalue of type 'const int'
            return *val;
                   ^~~~
zero/ifc/math/ops/arithmetic.cppm:25:16: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization 'zero::math::value_retriever<const int *>' requested here
        return value_retriever(std::forward<T>(lhs)) - value_retriever(std::forward<T>(rhs));
               ^
3 errors generated.
```

The call site:

```
const int a = 16;
const int b = 20;

std::cout << "Subtraction of two integers, passed as l-value references: " << zero::math::minus(&a, &b) << "\n\n";
```

I am failing to understand certain things about universal references.That's clear.
But the error that is making me mad is this:

```
indirection requires pointer
      operand ('int' invalid)
            return *val;
```

- How's this possible? If the type traits used in the `if constexpr` branch detected that `val` is a ptr or a reference, how can I have an error that says that `indirection requires ptr operand?
- How can improve the public API to work correctly with both values and/or pointers and references? So I am able to return a value `T`?

Comment: `const` rvalue reference doesn't appear meaningful to me – you'd have an rvalue reference if you wanted to move the data out, wouldn't you? Note that you *can* bind r-values to ordinary l-value references anyway.

Comment: `*val` and `std::is_reference`? Well, that at least requires an overloaded `operator*`, is this intended?

Comment: Your `minus`, as using `std::move`, enforces moving even if lhs and rhs are *not* r-value references (const l-value references). Pretty questionable... Why do you need r-value references at all?

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't need'em. I just need be able to work with ptr/refs and values

Comment: `*val` is never the value of `val` not matter if its a reference or forwarding reference. The value of `val` is `val`

Comment: I suppose what you want is either the value of `val` or the value it points to when its a pointer, but you dont say this in your post (neither is that what the code does)

Comment: On reading *'universal reference'* – did you happen do read [Scott Meyers](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)? Fall into that myself, too – there's no such specific *type* of universal (forwarding) references, it's part of normal template argument deduction: If you pass an r-value or r-value reference to a `&&` template parameter its type is deduced to r-value reference, otherwise l-value reference. Nothing more.

Comment: `if  ( is a pointer or is a reference) return *val;` is difficult to understand what you mean by this. `*val` makes sense when its a pointer, when its a reference then only maybe

Comment: the error you are getting is unrelated to forwarding and forwarding references.

Comment: decltype(val) is a reference because it's `const int &&` (I think) so the `if` statement is true

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "I suppose what you want is either the value of val or the value it points to when its a pointer, but you dont say this in your post (neither is that what the code does) " If my code were doing what I wanted, I wouldn't opened the question. And yes, that's exactly what I am looking for. 

I already tried with T&, but isn't working as expected. Numbers are `16` and `20`. So, 16 - 20 is 4, but the compiler is telling me that the result is 1. Funny joke. What I am not being able of handle well in the exact case that I describe in the question, then I pass a &

Comment: I just wanted to mention that you dont say it in the text and the code also does not speak for itself. Questions are subject to down and close votes when the clarification is only present in comments but not in the question.  I'd expect he question to start with something along the line of "I want to have a helper function that helps me to get the value or the value of the pointee when its a pointer."

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  In this case: "I want to have a helper function that helps me to get the value or the value of the pointee when its a pointer" your appreciation is perfectly understandable now. I edited the question to reflect it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed you want to instantiate the function template for `int` then this branch makes no sense:

```
if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<decltype(val)> || std::is_reference_v<decltype(val)>)
    return *val;
```

A reference to an `int` has no `operator*`.

The forwarding reference is a red herring. The error is not related to using a forwarding reference, and you do not need a forwarding reference when dealing with either `int` or `int*`.

Here is how you can do it:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
auto value_retriever(T& val) {
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
        return *val;
    else
        return val;
}

template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto minus(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) -> std::remove_pointer_t<T> {
    std::cout << value_retriever(lhs) << " - " << value_retriever(rhs) << "\n";
    return value_retriever(lhs) - value_retriever(rhs);
}

int main() {
    int x = 42;
    int y = 40;
    std::cout << minus(&x,&y) << "\n";
    std::cout << minus(x,y) << "\n";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K3Y9Kdz5T)

Comment: My bad, I answered you in the comments. I've tried with `T&`, which is the logical way of thinking about this for me, but it didn't work, so I went ahead with universal references hoping that I could help the compiler to deduce what I was expecting, but I failed misserably. You answer works well, but not in the case of l-value references, because it yiels an incorrect integer value for the proposed operation, even tho the code compiles without issues

Comment: @AlexVergara forwarding references (the official term for what Scott Meyers calls "universal reference" and unfortunately the old term is still around in articles) are totally unrelated to your issue and they do not help with the issue. If the solution in my answer does not work for you (after removing the forwarding stuff also from other code) then you need to post a [mcve]

Comment: @AlexVergara works fine here https://godbolt.org/z/8ech4eq6Y

Comment: @AlexVergara hm ok fails with pointers  https://godbolt.org/z/rvEPnTWfj, but thats an issue of your `minus`. Doesnt make sense to return `T` from `minus` when `T` is a pointer. You should really show a [mcve]

Comment: Oh sorry, I went for a copy and left the answer without send it. Omw to make the CE and make an MRE

Comment: Well, I just used your CE since there's mostly the MRE of my code. I just make a few adjustments to include certain things that we're talking in the answers of this questions https://godbolt.org/z/ezcTss76Y As you may notice, is returning 1, no matter what values you pass to the `minus` function. And what's more surprising to me, this code looks really similar to the overloads version of @Aconcagua but that returns the correct value, since the `if constexpr` only function does not

Comment: Oh, `auto` in the `value_retriever` does the trick. I prefer the `if constexpr` version, since the code is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> I don't need'em [r-value references]. I just need be able to work with ptr/refs and values

Then the simplest you can do is providing two separate overloads:

```
template <typename T>
T& valueRetriever(T& value) { return value; }
template <typename T>
T& valueRetriever(T* value) { return *value; }
```

No need to worry about r-value references any more (r-values can bind to `const` references anyway, even since long before r-value references existed at all) – and not about const-ness either (if `value` is reference or pointer to const then `T` is deduced as const type).

Your signature seems to imply you wanting to return a new value anyway, so you can reduce it to less complex

```
template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto minus(T const& lhs, T const& rhs)
{
    return value_retriever(lhs) - value_retriever(rhs);
}
```

Provided the corresponding `operator-` accepts by value or const-reference as well.

Comment: Your answer has the following issues:
      object of type 'const int *' with an rvalue of type 'int'
        return value_retriever(lhs) - value_retriever(rhs);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

And BTW, you mixed the function nomenclatures

Comment: @Aconcague `minus` must return `std::remove_pointer_t<T>`, or just `auto`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number applying `auto` as you suggested here makes the code of @Aconcagua works fine, returning the correct value

Comment: @AlexVergara Indeed – `T` originated yet from your question, just converted it from trailing into leading return type without further thinking about... Fixed now.